# ASN.1 encoding question

Tags: asn1

```
RecipientInfo ::= CHOICE {
ktri KeyTransRecipientInfo,
kari [1] KeyAgreeRecipientInfo,
kekri [2] KEKRecipientInfo,
pwri [3] PasswordRecipientInfo,
ori [4] OtherRecipientInfo }

KeyAgreeRecipientInfo ::= SEQUENCE { ... }
```

With the above ASN.1 schema, how would a `RecipientInfo.kari` be DER-encoded?

- `A1 <length> <KeyAgreeRecipientInfo fields>...`
- or `A1 <length> 30 <length> <KeyAgreeRecipientInfo fields>...`

The module uses implicit default tagging, so I reckon it should be the former, but Apple's security tool is encoding with the latter.

To see what I'm talking about, do:

```
security cms -E -r <identity> -i <file> | openssl asn1parse -inform der
```

and you'll see in the output:

```
24:d=4  hl=4 l= 374 cons: cont [ 1 ]        
28:d=5  hl=4 l= 370 cons: SEQUENCE
```

Thanks!